# Is eating chicken wings in Texas permissible?

Tags: halal-haram, food, meat

so I have been trying to become a better Muslim by learning what is allowed and what is not, and I have stumbled across the permissibility of eating meats. From what I know, we can only eat halal and Zabiha meats. The thing is however, in Texas most restaurants are not halal, so is it okay if I eat Buffal Wild Wings? Please use evidence as support if you can. Thanks all

Comment: Here some related posts: [Is it permissible to eat chicken and beef in a non-muslim country](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/24829/is-it-permissible-to-eat-chicken-and-beef-in-a-non-muslim-country) with further references and [How can we be sure that commercial businesses e.g. McDonalds serves halal food in a Muslim country](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/25895/how-can-we-be-sure-that-commercial-businesses-e-g-mcdonalds-that-are-present)

Comment: Kosher is also halal ([5:5](https://quran.com/5/5)), if you can ensure that no wine is used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have answered your own question. Just use a bit of deductive reasoning:-

> - Muslims cannot eat meat that is not Halal and Zabiha
> - Texas restaurants are not halal except when they are clearly labelled as halal
> - Thus, Muslims cannot eat from Texas restaurants except when they are clearly labelled as halal

Comment: Ok. That means I can’t eat in all the restaurants in my area.

Comment: @NB . I'm sure there are at least a few halal restaurants there.

Comment: There is literally one that’s 35 minutes away from where I live and all the other halal restaurants are over an hour away unfortunately. I have eaten out a lot so I know the area pretty well.